# Не могу правильно обратиться к сервлету

Tags: java, spring, mvc

Изучаю spring mvc, сборку делаю на maven.[image: структура проекта]

С одной из страниц, а именно из form я должен перейти к странице end. Но вместо этого получаю вот это :[image: error]

Код контроллера:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    public static void main(String args[]){
    }
    Hi hi=new Hi();
    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String home(){
        return hi.getHello();
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/form")
    public String form(){
        return "form";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/end") //method = RequestMethod.GET
    public String end(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws SQLException {
        String DB_URL = "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/postgres";
        String USER = "postgres";
        String PASS = "1234";
        System.out.println("Testing connection to PostgreSQL JDBC");
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("PostgreSQL JDBC Driver is not found. Include it in your library path ");
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        System.out.println("PostgreSQL JDBC Driver successfully connected");
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = DriverManager
                    .getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Connection Failed");
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        if (connection != null) {
            System.out.println("You successfully connected to database now");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to make connection to database");
        }

        Statement statement=connection.createStatement();
        statement.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS message (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY , text CHAR(30) NOT NULL) ;");
        String s=null;
        request.getParameter(s);
        if (s!=null) {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement=connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO message (text) VALUES (?);");
            preparedStatement.setString(1,s);
        }
        return "end";
    }
}
```

Код формы:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Form page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="GET" action="/end">
    <p><input type="text" name="text" id=""></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="submit"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

код конфига сервлета:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.Azat.Controller"/>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

код web.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.form</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

Сильно не ругайте, знаю что ошибка скорее всего глупая :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я просто переписал все заново и все работает) Причем немаловажную роль играло то, что idea в параметрах запуска проекта на сервере стоял localhost:8080/xxx где xxx это варник проекта. Мелочь, но столько времени было убито зря) поэтому при переходе на /end у меня ничего не выходило. рекомендую вообще через mvn jetty:run запускать)

Answer (score 0):

Что-то мне подсказывает (может быть stacktrace ошибки), что проблема где-то в этом месте

```
String s=null;
request.getParameter(s);
```

Если копать глубже, то Request не может распарсить строку запроса. Под рукой нет исходников jetty, поэтому не могу точно сказать где падает. Вы можете самостоятельно скопировать Stacktrace, и "погулять" по нему в IDEA.
Копируем Stacktrace и вставляем его в Analyze -> Analyze Stactrace.

Comment: Я просто переписал все заново и все работает) Причем немаловажную роль играло то, что idea в параметрах запуска проекта на сервере стоял http://localhost:8080/xxx/ где xxx это варник проекта. Мелочь, но столько времени было убито зря)